# pandas inner join on data frames without merging data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, inner-join

I have 2 indexed data frames (index on column 0):

```
0       1       2          3
JoeK    Joe     Kavanagh   joe.kavanagh@nomail.com
BarryD  Barry   Dempsy     bdempsy@nomail.com
OrlaF   Orla    Farrel     ofjk@nomail.com
SethB   Seth    Black      sblack@nomail.com
KateW   Kate    White      kw12@nomail.com
```

and the second one:

```
0       1       2          3
JoeK    Joe     Kavanagh   jkavanagh@nomail.com
BarryD  Barry   Dempsy     barry.dempsy@nomail.com
JimmyS  Jimmy   Smith      j.Smith@nomail.com
AndyB   Andy    Brown      ABrwn@nomail.com
MaryP   Mary    Power      MaryPower@nomail.com
```

I would like to perform an inner join like in the following SQL:

```
SELECT df2.* FROM df2
INNER JOIN df1
ON df2.0 = df1.0
```

Where I only get the results from the 2nd data frame, and not both:

```
0       1       2          3
JoeK    Joe     Kavanagh   jkavanagh@nomail.com
BarryD  Barry   Dempsy     barry.dempsy@nomail.com
```

I tried the pandas merge, but it gives me the result from both data frames!
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than a merge you want to just filter your second df by testing membership of the values against the other df using [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
In [16]:
df1[df1['0'].isin(df['0'])]

Out[16]:
        0      1         2                        3
0    JoeK    Joe  Kavanagh     jkavanagh@nomail.com
1  BarryD  Barry    Dempsy  barry.dempsy@nomail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want an **inner** [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (the default is to do an outer). You also need to first restrict `df1` to the merge columns:

```
In [11]: df2.merge(df1[['0']], how="inner", on=['0'])  # equivalently df1[['0']].merge(df2, how="inner", on=['0'])
Out[11]:
        0      1         2                        3
0    JoeK    Joe  Kavanagh     jkavanagh@nomail.com
1  BarryD  Barry    Dempsy  barry.dempsy@nomail.com
```

If you don't do the restriction (`df1[['0']]`) it'll suffix the overlapping columns:

```
In [12]: df2.merge(df1, how="inner", on=['0'])
Out[12]:
        0    1_x       2_x                      3_x    1_y       2_y                      3_y
0    JoeK    Joe  Kavanagh     jkavanagh@nomail.com    Joe  Kavanagh  joe.kavanagh@nomail.com
1  BarryD  Barry    Dempsy  barry.dempsy@nomail.com  Barry    Dempsy       bdempsy@nomail.com
```

The suffixes can be configured with the `suffixes` kwarg.

*[See also the pandas docs for a "brief primer on merge methods"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).*

Comment: The OP seems to want to filter though judging from their desired output

Comment: @EdChum My understanding is that a join is going to be a *lot* faster than an isin call...

Comment: That wasn't my point, only that the output seems to me to want a filter rather than merge the op may be after that in reality but there's been no response as yet

Comment: Well, an inner join **is** a filter, especially in the case where there is no additional columns to merge in.